# Laravel 5.3 How does bootstrap interpret and display items without internet

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, font-awesome

I'm still learning Laravel 5.3 and started studying it a few days ago. One tutorial project I'm following made use of `Fontawesome` and `Bootstrap` where bootstrap link and `fontawesome` link was included within the `<head></head>` tag.

So I thought that if I disconnect the internet connection, it will fail to display the icons from `fontawesome` since no library file was downloaded and imported to project. But I was surprised that it still was able to display the `fontawesome` icons.

That's when I of thought of asking this simple question since I'm a beginner with `Laravel` and web programming. (`Java` programmer)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <!-- bootstrap link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- fontawesome link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- app.css link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/app.css') }}">


    @yield('styles')
</head>
```

I read something from `Laravel 5.3` documentation about the bootstrap directory that stores `cached` information. Is the caching the reason the `fontawesome` icons still displays even when it is not connected to the internet?

> The Bootstrap Directory
>
> The bootstrap directory contains files that bootstrap the framework
>   and configure autoloading. This directory also houses a cache
>   directory which contains framework generated files for performance
>   optimization such as the route and services cache files.

I'd appreciate any explanation to this so I can better understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser has cache too. Do [hard refresh / reload](https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome) - in Chrome you can do this by opening inspector and then right click on refresh button and click what suits you the most.

[image: hard-reload]

> Describing what is actually going on would be too long for an answer.

Good description what is going on is [here](https://thesocietea.org/2016/05/how-browser-caching-works/).

Google search terms: `browser cache`, `web browser cache`

---

If you use build system (gulp) you will most likely end up with large `*.css` file which contains bootstrap, font-awesome definitions etc.

More on that is right in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#installation).

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that if cached files were deleted or emptied, there's no way for icons from fontawesome or some other bootsrap libraries to display when internet is disabled?

Comment: @p3ace You mean you want to do the developing without internet connection? It is possible: I just made an edit; you "pre download" source files for bootstrap, font-awesome, jQuery... whatever you need, using Bower or NPM. Later if you make change you run build command and you load all your css and script files from "localhost", do reasearch `gulp`, `npm`, `build`, `grunt`, `elixir`. Essentially you are looking for this https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/6 - free tutorial on the topic.

Comment: Okay I got it. I think I'll just download the sources files. Thanks for the idea about gulp, npm, build, grunt and elixir. I have no knowledge about those for now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @p3ace please see updated comment with link to free tutorial